# Conditional Delete of TD Element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm new on Ajax and in Stack Overflow (even if I read a lot of threads).
I need to delete an element (`class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper">`) of the table  just in case that there are more then one element with the same `<td>` tag.

```
<table class="rsTimelineTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-right:0px none;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rsAllDayRow">
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div>  <!--DO NOT DELETE -->
            </td>
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div> <!--DO NOT DELETE -->
            </td>
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap" style="z-index:7;">
                <div id="ctl00_M_RadScheduler1_82_0" class="rsApt rsFlownDay" style="height:100%;width:100%;" title="17.10"></div>
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div> <!TO  DELETE -->
            </td>
            <!-- Other TD tag>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="rsTimelineTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-right:0px none;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rsAllDayRow">
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div> <!--DO NOT DELETE -->
            </td>
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div> <!--DO NOT DELETE -->
            </td>
            <td class="rsAllDayCell">
                <div class="rsWrap" style="z-index:7;">
                <div id="ctl00_M_RadScheduler1_82_0" class="rsApt rsFlownDay" style="height:100%;width:100%;" title="17.10"></div>
                <div class="rsWrap rsLastSpacingWrapper"> </div> <!-- TO DELETE -->
            </td>
            <!-- Other TD tag>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="rsTimelineTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-right:0px none;">
    <!-- etc etc -->
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to remove duplicates or just remove the last tds containing an element with those classes.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last element with the rsWrap rsLastspacingWrapper class you can do.

```
$(".rsWrap, .rsLastSpacingWrapper").last().remove();
```

To remove it from each table you could try (untested):

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $(".rsWrap, .rsLastSpacingWrapper").last().remove();
});
```

Not quite sure how correct my syntax is there but it should at least give you an idea of where to start.